# How to call properties on a same column in a group of objects? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, import

I have a class called `Terminal` which can receive a group of `arguments` from multiple instances.

Every time when `Terminal` gets the `arguments`, a new object called `this.cells` stores them, and push it into a new `Array` called `this.mesh`.

My goal is to call all of the properties on same column no matter how I named to call them.

So when if I type `console.log(this.mesh.location)`, a result would be like this:

```
23         // Person   | constructor(name, age, gender)      |
New York   // Job      | constructor(name, location, salary) |
20         // Angle    | constructor(name, size, color)      |
//---------------------+-------------------------------------+

// All values showed up because these properties were on the same column
```

A problem is the first array can't find rest of the objects except the first one ([0]) **even the console shows all 3 objects** like this:

[image]

But if I inspect `this.mesh[1]`, the first array is giving `undefined`:

[image]

The 3 objects must be inside each of the arrays so that I can compare those `keys` and select the specific `values` using `Hashtable` or `Proxy`.

Any solutions to fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
// person.mjs
import Terminal from './terminal.mjs';
class Person {
    constructor(name, age, gender, input) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.input = input || new Terminal(this);
        // console.log(this.input.name);
        // this.input.event();
    }
}
let p1 = new Person('James', 23, 'Male');

// job.mjs
import Terminal from './terminal.mjs';
class Job {
    constructor(name, location, salary, input) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.salary = salary
        this.input = input || new Terminal(this);
        // console.log(this.input.name);
    }
}
let a1 = new Job('Web Developer', 'New York', 40000);

// shape.mjs
import Terminal from './terminal.mjs';
class Shape {
    constructor(name, size, color, input) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
        this.input = input || new Terminal(this);
    }
}
let s1 = new Shape('Triangle', 20, 'Blue');

// terminal.mjs
export default class Terminal {
    constructor(...output) {
        /* Define an Array */
        this.mesh = Array.prototype;

        /* Assign, insert a group of contents to a new object */
        this.cells = Object.assign({}, ...output);

        /* able to call the specific variables from the other js files. */
        /* can call the variable without [] notation. */
        this.pylon = Object.assign(Object.prototype, ...output);

        /* Put it into the Array */
        this.mesh.push(this.cells);

        /* consoling */
        // console.log(this.mesh[1]) // Gives undefined the first array.
        console.log(this.mesh.location);
    }
}
```

---

**Attempt 1**

According to Jonas' answer, but I can't get a rest of values because `this.mesh` does not stack the `objects` into the 1 array.

If I `console.log(this.mesh);` the browser throws this result:

> [{…}] terminal0.mjs:14
>
> [{…}] terminal0.mjs:14
>
> [{…}] terminal0.mjs:14

```
export default class Terminal {
    constructor(...output) {
        this.log = console.log('------------------');
        /* Array */
        this.mesh = [];

        /* Assign the objects */
        this.cells = Object.assign({}, ...output);

        /* Push it into the Array */
        this.mesh.push(this.cells);

        /* Proxy */
        this.bridge.age;
    }
    get bridge() {
        let handler = {
            get(target, property, receiver) {
                let value = Object.keys(target[0]).indexOf(property);
                target.map(object => {
                    let refined = Object.values(object)[value];
                    console.log(refined);
                })
            }
        }
        return new Proxy(this.mesh, handler);
    }
}
```

---

**Attempt 2**

This time I've used `async` for collecting the objects but it gives the same result my original question.

```
export default class Terminal {
    constructor(...output) {
        this.output = output;
        this.bridge();
    }
    async bridge() {
        let getObjects = new Promise((res, rej) => {
            this.mesh = Array.prototype;
            this.cells = Object.assign({}, ...this.output);
            this.mesh.push(this.cells);
            res(this.mesh);
        }),
            patch = await getObjects;
        console.log(this.mesh[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your issue. Do you want to share the `mesh` array instance in Terminal between the three other instances (Person, Job, Shape)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are trying to instantiate `new Terminal(this)` multiple time, By doing that every time new instance of Terminal class invoked you loos other context and also have side effects.

My opinion is use a singleton method for `terminal.js`. Example below

```
// terminal.js
class Terminal {
  constructor() {
    this.cells = [];
    this.mesh = [];
  }
  get(propName) {
    try {
      //Define the variable to store the index position of cells
      let finalIndex = "";

      //Find the index position of the property
      this.cells.forEach(cell => {
        let index = cell.indexOf(propName);
        if (index !== -1) {
          finalIndex = index;
        }
      });

      //Check if the finalIndex is there
      if (finalIndex >= 0) {
        //Find the values by index
        const finalData = this.mesh.map(data => data[finalIndex]);
        console.log(finalData);
      } else {
        throw new Error(`No property named ${propName} found!`);
      }
    } catch (msg) {
      console.error(msg);
    }
  }
  set(...output) {
    //Create a new ref object
    const data = Object.assign({}, ...output);

    //Set the keys in a 2-D array structure
    this.cells.push(Object.keys(data));

    //Set the values in a 2-D array structure
    this.mesh.push(Object.values(data));
  }
}
const instance = new Terminal();

// Singleton
Object.freeze(instance);

module.exports = instance;
```

`index.js`

```
var Terminal = require("./terminal.js");
require("./job");
require("./person");
require("./shape");
Terminal.get("location"); // [ 'New York', 23, 20 ]
Terminal.get("name"); // [ 'Web Developer', 'James', 'Triangle' ]
Terminal.get("gender"); // [ 40000, 'Male', 'Blue' ]
```

Here is the sample code which solved your problem. 
https://repl.it/@pandasanjay/stackoverflow-57900065

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed. I've almost given up and tried to create my own database for doing this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks you liked it. But I really don't understand your use case here. This is looks like you are over complicating the solution. Please do revisit you solution and get reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const data = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 1, d: 2 }];

  const position = Object.keys(data[0]).indexOf("a");

  const result = data.map(obj => Object.values(obj)[position]);
```

You can use `Object.keys` and `Object.values` to access the object keys/values as arrays.

---

As a sidenote, this:

```
   /* Define an Array */
    this.mesh = Array.prototype;
```

Makes litlle sense. No new array gets created. Also the comment says exactly the same as the line below. Just do

```
  this.mesh = [];
```

Comment: The reason I used `Array.prototype` instead of `[]` notation was the browser couldn't group up the `objects` like this: `[{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 1, d: 2 }];`. When I use `[]` notation, the code makes 3 separated arrays. And I've just tested it using this way, but it gives an error. I've posted the errors and the code I've done.